# Gspread causes costs?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, gspread

I need to do operations in a google sheet with python. I'm searching for a library that help me in this task.

I found Gspread. But I need to know if the library causes costs in my account of google. I asked to Bard, and says that gspread uses a protocol API REST of Google, taht is free. Someone knows if that is real

I have search in the gspread's documentation, but a didn't find anything

Comment: `pygsheets` may be of interest see [link](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Feed" a google spreadsheet without using Google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579782/feed-a-google-spreadsheet-without-using-google-cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi **gspread does not cause cost**, the API used by gspread has some limits.

If you reach them you'll be blocked.

If you need to overcome them then you need to pay Google for it

You can validate that too by the fact that you can enable the Google Sheet HTTP API without putting any credit card number anywhere.